# Neo4j query multiple hops

Tags: database, neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

Hi guys I am trying to write a neo4j query to get multiple hops.

Currently my schema is 
authors - fname,lname & 
paper - title

relationship: author -> WROTE -> paper

```
MATCH (a:Author)-[:WROTE]->(p:Paper)
WITH a as auth1, count(p.title) as count1
MATCH (auth1) -[:WROTE *1]->(p2:Paper),
              (auth2)-[:WROTE *1]->(p2)
WHERE count1 > 7
RETURN DISTINCT auth1.fname, auth1.lname, auth2.fname,  auth2.lname
```

What I am trying to do is find everyone connected to my author who has the most papers authored - for starters 1 hop, then 2 hops etc.  I know the author with the most papers has 8 written thus why my count > 7; however I don't think my query is right.  Whenever I change

```
:WROTE *1 to :WROTE *1..2
```

the results are the same which I believe they shouldn't be - any help would be appreciated

Comment: I assumer a paper can have multiple authors, correct?

Comment: yes papers can have multiple authors

Comment: What is your understanding about what `[:WROTE*1..2]` is doing? Since you're using [:WROTE*1] (which isn't necessary to use *1) I have a feeling you might be misunderstanding something

Comment: inverse i thought that *1 would return everyone who was a co-author and *1..2 would return everyone who is a co-author(y) with author x and everyone who was a co-author with (y) so 2 hops away from my author x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[EDITED]

Below is a query that does not need to know beforehand how many papers your  most productive author (co)wrote. It automatically determines who that author is, and then finds all of his/her co-authors and their co-authors. For this to work, the `-[:WROTE*..3]-` pattern is nondirectional and uses an upper bound of 3 (since there would be a hop of 3 relationships to get to the coauthors of the coauthors). In general, if you want coauthors to a depth of N, you need an upper bound of `(1+(N-1)*2)`.

```
MATCH (auth1:Author)-[:WROTE]->(p:Paper)
WITH auth1, COUNT(p) AS count1
ORDER BY count1 DESC LIMIT 1
MATCH (auth1)-[:WROTE]->(:Paper)-[:WROTE*..3]-(auth2:Author)
RETURN DISTINCT auth1.fname, auth1.lname, auth2.fname,  auth2.lname;
```

In addition, if you want to visualize in the neo4j Browser all the co-authors of interest and their co-written papers, this should work:

```
MATCH (auth1:Author)-[:WROTE]->(p:Paper)
WITH auth1, COUNT(p) AS count1
ORDER BY count1 DESC LIMIT 1
MATCH path=(auth1)-[:WROTE]->(:Paper)-[:WROTE*..3]-(auth2:Author)
WITH auth1, auth2, NODES(path) AS ns
RETURN DISTINCT auth1, auth2, [i IN RANGE(1, SIZE(ns)-1, 2) | ns[i]] AS papers
```

`RANGE(1, SIZE(ns)-1, 2)` returns a list of the indexes of the `Paper` nodes in each `path` (since they have the odd indexes).

*Make sure to disable the `Connect result nodes` option in `Browser Settings`, or else the visualization may show extra nodes that are not in the results.*

Comment: sam this gets me everyone who is a co-author with author1 what if i want 2 hops how would I go about doing this? Also yes this result is the same as mine it's when I move to 2 hops away where I need help.  Meaning I also want everyone who is a co-author with my original set of co-authors.

Comment: ohhhhh ok my confusion was i think the n-1 to actually get to the authors.  I didn't realize that  *1..2 wouldn't get me to the actual co-authors of co-authors.  Thank you so much this makes so much more sense now!

Comment: hey sam another question if you wouldn't mind appending to this answer as I am curious.  Since this only returns the row data I'd like to see the visualization.  I have it currently showing me part of this by returning auth1, auth2 and i defined the paper between auth1 and auth2 as p so I'm returning that.  I get most connections but I don't get the papers connecting between the co-author to their co-authors any idea how to get those papers out of this?

Comment: With respect to your next-to-last comment: Also, the variable-length path needed to be non-directional, and needed to specify the `Author` label for `auth2` to prevent getting back `Paper`s.

Comment: See my updated answer for a query that should let you visualize the co-authors and the co-authored papers.

Comment: I believe the 2 queries result in different answers - when I increase the limit from 1 to 10 both of those queries return different numbers of authors? For example when I do a limit of 9 - the top one returns 207 authors and the bottom returns 186 authors

Comment: Did you disable the `Connect result nodes` option in `Browser Settings`? See my updated answer.

Comment: I dont have that option in my browser settings any other way to do it

Comment: Does your Browser have a gear icon? Click that to access the Settings.

Comment: If you are using neo4j 3.2.2+, you can also enter this command in the browser: `:config {autoComplete: false}` to disable that option.

Comment: yeah it does im running 3.1.3 ill update though to a newer version and see what happens

Comment: Still not working for me.  In my graph based one I have significantly less results - for example when I do top 20 people I get 213 authors in my graph but in my row one (1st query) I get 409.  Now there can be some overlap so to check that I just returned the first query with just auth2.fname, auth2.lname and that results in 342 authors.  Thus the graph should at leas have 342 why is the graph only getting 213? Am I just misunderstanding something?

Comment: The browser has a default limit of 300 for the number of nodes it will display for query results. You can change that (in 3.2.2+) to, say, 1000 by using this browser command: `:config initialNodeDisplay: 1000`.

Comment: think that was it now I'm getting 345 authors which seems much more realistic